# How can a 16bit Processor have 4 byte sized long int?

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-architecture

[image]

I've problem with the size of `long int` on a 16-bit CPU. Looking at its architecture:

[image]

No register is more than 16-bit long. So, how come `long int` can have more than 16bits. In fact, according to me for any Processor, the maximum size of the data type must be the size of the general purpose register. Am I right?

Comment: that's not true, think of a processor with 32 bit registers dealing with 64 bit double values - it may not be as efficient, but in the less common cases where you need wider data types, you can handle them

Comment: @AK4749: Double values are dealt with in floating point registers. Which as far as I remember have size double than general purpose registers. Is it not so?

Comment: you could be right, I just knew there were 64 bit data types before 64 bit processors haha, let me go investigate

Comment: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/978-c-language-handling-64-bit-integers so yeah, there were longer integers before 64 bit processors came out, but even today, the largets FP register is 64 bit, which isn't double of 64 bit regular registers, so if it's not true now, maybe it wasn't true at some point?

Comment: 32 bit machines have been doing 80 bit floating point math for a decade or more now.  ability and performance are two different things.  the OP question is about maximum size of a data type.  software allows for infinitely sized (up to your storage limit) operations independent of the size of the alu.  an 8 bit processor can do 80 bit floating point math or 2048 bit fixed point math, not a problem.  despite many designs not only not having fpus but not having divide operations and some without multiplies we still can run linux on those systems and multiply and divide fixed and float.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. In fact the C and C++ standards require that `sizeof(long int) >= 4`.*

(I'm assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8` in this case.)

This is the same deal with 64-bit integers on 32-bit machines. The way it is implemented is to use two registers to represent the lower and upper halves.

Addition and subtraction are done as two instructions:

On x86:

- Addition: `add` and `adc` where `adc` is "add with carry"
- Subtraction: `sub` and `sbb` where `sbb` is "subtract with borrow"

For example:

```
long long a = ...;
long long b = ...;

a += b;
```

will compile to something like:

```
add eax,ebx
adc edx,ecx
```

Where `eax` and `edx` are the lower and upper parts of `a`. And `ebx` and `ecx` are the lower and upper parts of `b`.

Multiplication and division for double-word integers is more complicated, but it follows the same sort of grade-school math - but where each "digit" is a processor word.

Comment: No, they require that `long` have a width of at least 32. `sizeof(long)` could be 2 if, for example, the range of `unsigned char` were 0-65536.

Comment: It's entirely possible to have `sizeof(T) == 1` for *all* integral types. Were you thinking of "conversion rank"?

Comment: Even though, this was not part of the question. How on earth, is a byte not equal to 8 bits? :O

Comment: @claws The C and C++ standards say nothing about how large a byte is (other than being at least 8 bits IIRC) - despite the fact that it's almost always equal to 8 bits.

Comment: @claws A byte - in C or C++ - is, by definition, the number of bits a `char` has. So have a machine with 32-bit `char`s, and you have one with 32-bit bytes.

Answer (score 2):

No. If the machine doesn't have registers that can handle 32-bit values, it has to simulate them in software. It could do this using the same techniques that are used in any library for arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: Also, in some cases, there may be an extension or coprocessor that can handle larger than register numbers. (for example, on the 32-bit x86, SSE can handle 64-bit numbers (albeit, much less easier)